# Rendering Items Array in localStorage to Unordered List

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

When I click DisplayBtn() it should sets the display state to true and display myLeads Array from localStorage. localStorage contains MyLeads Array and I've used a map() in an attempt to fetch items and place them in an unordered list. I've done this before on arrays and it has worked but its not currently working.

Basically, I just want them items in localStorage to render in an unordered list. I've attempted several approaches to solve this issue my latest error message is `'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')'`

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import List from './components/List'
import { SaveBtn } from './components/Buttons';

function App() {

  const [myLeads, setMyLeads] = useState([]);
  const [leadValue, setLeadValue] = useState({
    inputVal: ""
  })

  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setLeadValue((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  };


  const [localItems, setLocalItems] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myLeads"))
  );

  const displayLocalItems = localItems.map((item) => {
    return <List key={item} val={item}/>
  })


  const saveBtn = () => {
    setMyLeads(prev => [...prev, leadValue.inputVal]);

    localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    setLocalItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, leadValue.inputVal]);

    setDisplay(false);
  };

  const displayBtn = () => {
     setDisplay(true)
  };

  
  return (
    <main>
      <input
        name="inputVal"
        value={leadValue.inputVal}
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
      />

      <SaveBtn saveBtn={saveBtn} />

      <button onClick={displayBtn}>Display Leads</button>
    
      {display && (
      {displayLocalItems}
      )
    }
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you call map before you save anything to local storage - at that point, it's null

Comment: like I think this is null if it doesn't exist yet `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myLeads"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
const [localItems, setLocalItems] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myLeads")) || []);
```

So if the local storage is empty you initialize your state to an empty array, which can be safely mapped.